# TFS with no branches

Tags: tfs

Someone setup a Team Project in our TFS environment that has no branches, only the solution, code files and folders.

Team Project-->
     --Folder A
     --Folder B
     --project.sln

I'd like to create a branch under that team project and move those folders and files into that branch and I am at a loss on how to do this.  Has anyone encounterd this before?  How do I do what I am trying to do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I would create a new Folder(s) at the top Level so you have

```
$/TeamProject/Main
```

Now perform a "Move" of your current top level stuff into `Main` and check it it.

Once you have that, you can right click on `Main` and select the "Convert to Branch" option. This will make it a branch in TFS.

Comment: @MichaelC, no problems, in the [spirit of Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask), can you please mark it as the accepted answer? Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Team Explorer -> Source Control -> Branching and Merging (Right Click Menu) -> Branch

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Alex!  I try that and when prompted for the target and I select the same team project it tells me it already exists and if I try to another name/target I get an message stating that it doesn't exist.

I'm not sure how this project was created with the source code and solution not under a single folder or branch.  I haven't been able to duplicate it to even see how to fix it.

Would it be better to remove it from source control, create a new team project and then add back to source control?  Isn't hard to remove all references to souce control?

Comment: I'm not sure how it's better to fix it. This person, who added it to TFS, he is not working with you? Can you ask him?